# Android passing data from fragment button to textview of activity

Tags: android-fragments

I have two layout.

The first one is LinearLayout with a TextView and a fragment

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
         android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Class MainActivity, using **ViewPager** to slide betwwen two fragment layout

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case 0: return SimpleKeypad.newInstance("SimpleKeypad, Instance 1");
            case 1: return AdvanceKeypad.newInstance("AdvanceKeypad, Instance 1");
            default: return AdvanceKeypad.newInstance("AdvanceKeypad, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

}

Fragment layout has a button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
   />
```

My question is how to set text to the Textview inside MainActivity layout when click on the Button inside the fragment layout?

Thank you in advanced. I'l really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to directly access the TextView from within the fragment. This will crash with a NullPointerException if you the view is not found.

```
((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Goodbye");
```

You can also implement a method within MainActivity which provides better abstraction. For instance:

```
public void setTitle(final String title) {
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(title);
}
```

And then call that from your fragment

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("Goodbye");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is solution for my problem.

Comment: I'm glad that it meets your needs. Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Write an interface in your Fragment class
Also implements onClickListener to handle button click event in Fragment class as below

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private Callback callback;
...
...

onClick(View v) {
    callback.setTextToView("Message to be set");
}

public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public interface Callback {
    void setTextToView(String messageToShow);
}
```

}

then in your activity implement that interface as below

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

...
...
onCreate(...) {

    myFragment = new MyFragment();
    // add your fragment to activity
    myFragment.setCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void setTextToView(String messageToShow) {
    myTextview.setText(messageToShow);
}
```

}

inside setTextToView() you can set value to textview which declared in Activity